# Laravel Queue:work running forever in host?

Tags: laravel, laravel-scheduler

I have a question about Laravel queue. 
first of all My queue driver is database, if I once call the cron job with command queue:work, the queue will work forever? or i must define a cron job run every minutes?

Comment: check your laravel.log file, you definitely got some error in your job..

Comment: @ankitpatel my question is about cron job.. i need set a cron to call queue:work every minutes? or its done with call yearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set your command or queue for every minute in Console/Kernel.php file's Schedule function

Command:

```
$schedule->command('your-command')->everyMinute();
```

Job:

```
$schedule->job(new JOBCLASS)->everyMinute();
```

then you need to enter

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

in your crontab file on server which check every minute in your kernel file to check whether any command is set or not

Comment: What is the difference between **** php /path artisan queue:work and **** php /path sheduler:run?

Comment: @MortezaNegahi Queues and schedulers are totally different things! read the docs!

Comment: But sheduler:run run my job and queue:work run it too ! i cant feel this diffrently, thank you for big help :-)

Comment: You need to set scheduler to run your job.. the answer which I mentioned above will set your all job in database jobs table. and scheduler will check every minute is there any entry in jobs table or not

Comment: once you set scheduler, you don't need to run schedule:run